# Django template not refreshing when using python requests API client

Tags: django, python-requests, flask-restful

I am reading from a flask REST API using python's Requests library and referencing this in a Django view.

The issue i am experiencing is when testing the API call from a Chrome plugin i am seeing a refreshed response where as in the Django template I'm not seeing any change in data when the page is refreshed.

I have a small lib which includes a GET call to the API:

```
    def container_list():
        api_auth = get_auth()
        server_url = get_server_url() + '/v1/containers'
        r = requests.get(server_url , auth = api_auth)
        return r.json()
```

I am then reading this in the view:

```
    from django.views.generic import ListView
    from lib.ApiClient import image_list, container_list
    from django.core.cache import cache

    class ContainerList(ListView):
        template_name = 'containers.html'
        cache.clear() # Attempt at clearing the cache
        queryset=container_list()
```

This is then served to the template:

```
    {% for container in object_list %}
        {% for key,value in container.items %}
            {{key}} : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions on how i can get the template to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ListView` incorrectly. You assign `queriset` attribute with something that is not a `QuerySet`. This means that you fetch the data only once (at the moment of importing the `views.py`).

Every time when the request to the view comes it uses the data in the `queryset` attribute. If you want to fetch new data on every request you need to overwrite `get_queryset` method. Something like:

```
class ContainerList(ListView):
    template_name = 'containers.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return container_list()
```

This will fetch the data on every request.

Comment: As per my reply in the Django Facebook group, I had a suspicion it was bad use of the queryset. Many thanks for providing a simple and effective solution. The page now serves the correct updated content.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you will need a signal processor to watch for changes, and when it notices a change, it will update via an AJAX call to the template, replacing with new data.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I am still very new to Django so will have a look at how this can be implemented.. If you know of any good examples of a similar signal watch process, please do post a link. 

Cheers Piers